# Can't use ICommand attribute in view model using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm

Tags: c#, mvvm, community-toolkit-mvvm

In my view models, I wanted to use the source generators in CommunityToolkit.Mvvm but for some reason I can't seem to use `[ICommand]` attribute with my action methods.

The error I get is:

> Cannot apply attribute class 'ICommand' because it is abstract

Here's the base class for my view model model.

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
    public partial class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        bool isBusy = false;

        [ObservableProperty]
        string title = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

And here's my view model class:

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   [ObservableProperty]
   string firstName;

   [ObservableProperty]
   string lastName;

   [ICommand] // <-- This is where I get the error I mentioned above
   async Task DoSomething()
   {
       // Do something here...
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey Sam, I'll try to reproduce this when I have some free time.

Comment: Perhaps you're accidentally using the ICommand interface from System.Windows.Input, instead of the ICommandAttribute from the CommunityTookit. Try to replace `[ICommand]` with `[CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.ICommand]` and see if that was the case.

Comment: I was sure you were right because I am using `System.Windows.Input` but I don't find `ICommand` in `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.ICommand`. I'm using version `8.0.0-preview4`. The only thing I see in there is `RelayCommand` but that I can't seem to use it as an attribute and it doesn't work in the above example.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**EDIT**

Yes, they've renamed the `ICommandAttribute` to `RelayCommandAttribute`. It's metioned in the breaking changes section of the [8.0.0-preview4 release notes](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/releases/tag/v8.0.0-preview4).

**Original answer**

The problem seems to be what @Luca Clavarino mentioned in the comments:

> Perhaps you're accidentally using the ICommand interface from System.Windows.Input,instead of the `ICommandAttribute` from the CommunityTookit. Try to replace `[ICommand]` with `[CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input.ICommand]` and see if that was the case.

And I think I know why this might be happening to you. The **`ICommandAttribute` seems to be missing in CommunityToolkit.Mvvm 8.0.0-preview4** so intellisense won't offer the `using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input` statement and instead offers `using System.Windows.Input;`.

The problem can be resolved by **downgrading to CommunityToolkit.Mvvm 8.0.0-preview3**, that version works fine for me.

Here's a working sample (using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm 8.0.0-preview3).

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;

namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
    public partial class BaseViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        bool isBusy = false;

        [ObservableProperty]
        string title = string.Empty;
    }

    public partial class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        string firstName;

        [ObservableProperty]
        string lastName;

        [ICommand] //works in 8.0.0-preview3
        async Task DoSomething()
        {
            // Do something here...
        }
    }
}
```

I've also noticed that while the **`ICommandAttribute` is gone** in 8.0.0-preview4, there's a **`RelayCommandAttribute` instead**. Maybe they've simply renamed it.

Using the `RelayCommandAttribute` instead of `ICommandAttribute` in 8.0.0-preview4 seems to be working.

```cs
[RelayCommand] //works in 8.0.0-preview4
async Task DoSomething()
{
    // Do something here...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! As you said, `[ICommand]` is now `[RelayCommand]` and another important point is that if we name the method `DoSomething()`, the generated command will be `DoSomethingCommand()`. This is the reason why I couldn't get `[RelayCommand]` to work before. Once I referenced the method with `Command` suffix, it worked fine. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Excellent, this is the only helpful thread that answers a search of "relaycommand is not an attribute class".

Answer (score 17):

The accepted answer has a lot of text just to say in [8.0.0 Preview 4](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/releases/tag/v8.0.0-preview4) the `[ICommand]` attribute was renamed to `[RelayCommand]`. It is listed in the breaking changes of the [release notes](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/releases/tag/v8.0.0-preview4).

Comment: I figured as much. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Works with 8.0.0-preview3 not 8.0.0-preview4 or latest release 8.0.0.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you download the current version of CommunityTookkit.Mvvm 8.2.2 above it actually   `[RelayCommand]` this will work hope this helps